# Strange router behavior -- packet loss, truncated HTTP responses

Tags: router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, packet-loss

I am encountering some strange behavior with a new home WiFi router. Pinging outside servers (i.e. google.com, amazon.com) has 30% packet loss, and HTTP requests with `wget` only give me the first 1-2kB of the response (leading to pages also not loading in the browser).

I tried lowering the MTU from 1500 to 1460. I'm connecting this up to a switch on a campus LAN.

Is it likely that this unit is just a dud?

EDIT: I am not using the wireless LAN yet, just the wired hub.

Comment: many wifi routers have a wired ethernet lan port... do you have the same issue on the wired lan port?

Comment: whats the make and model of your new router? have you been playing with any firewall rules especially those related to packet fragmentation? Unless this is a problem of your own making, you are probably dealing with a hardware/firmware issue. have you tried upgrading your firmware?

Comment: @MikePennington, I forgot to mention that this is all through the wired LAN port. I will add that to the question.

Comment: @FrankThomas, nope, I have not touched any firewall rules, but I will try upgrading the firmware before returning it. Thanks for the responses so far everyone, this is a great Q&A community. EDIT: the make and model is Linksys N300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are receiving 30% packet loss it is most likely an issue with either the router or the amount of wireless noise in the area.  You might want to see if using a different channel works, or if moving the device closer to the WIFI router.

As someone else commented, see if you can plug a device into the router and if the packet loss goes away.  This could go a small way towards working out if the packet loss is creeping in on the WAN side of the connection or if its related to wireless.

If you are experiencing problems with (standard) ping, the issue is almost certainly not MTU related, although if ping works but sessions freeze, then MTU is definately a good place to look.